# apache vitual host (EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00547: Could not resolve host name

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualhost

i am getting this error my site can not start up
(EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00547: Could not resolve host name betatgh.tgi.na -- ignoring!

my host config file looks like that

```
<VirtualHost betatgh.tgi.na:80>
  

        ServerName betatgh.tgi.na
        ServerAdmin itwhk@tgh.na
        ServerAlias www.betatgh.tgi.na
        DocumentRoot /var/www/betatgh.tgi.na
        #Redirect "/" "http://betatgh.tgi.na/"
        <Directory /var/www/betatgh.tgi.na/>
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
           Require all granted
           AllowOverride all
        </Directory>

        

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define betatgh.tgi.na in your dns.

For instance use CNAME to point to tgi.na